# How render HTML file in Angular component?

Tags: html, angular

I want to render a HTML file into a component. This HTML has some libraries connected to it which show certain content. How can this be done? I tried DomSanitizer but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the file using typescript/javascript.
2. Depending on your HTML, you can use `[innerHtml]` attribute. [See](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding)

**Code:**

```
<div [innerHtml]="yourHTML"></div>
```

Note: Be aware of XSS vulnerability.